# Removing digits from a word

Tags: python, regex

Say I have a sentence that contains words, integers and combinations thereof:

```
"This is a string with an integer 1 and a 2 and a 3 and a 1A69 and a 1B and a C3"
```

Is it possible to strip all integers from words that consist of letters *and* integers? I.e., I want the above to become

```
"This is a string with an integer 1 and a 2 and a 3 and a A and a B and a C"
```

Comment: You should use a RegEx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be to remove digits that are preceded (with *look behind* `?<=` syntax) or followed (with *lookahead* `?=` syntax) by letters:

```
import re
s = "This is a string with an integer 1 and a 2 and a 3 and a 1A69 and a 1B and a C3"

re.sub(r'\d+(?=[a-zA-Z])|(?<=[a-zA-Z])\d+', '', s)
# 'This is a string with an integer 1 and a 2 and a 3 and a A and a B and a C'
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, without regex:

```
def remove_digits(s):
    return ''.join([x for x in s if not x.isdigit()])

def is_combined(s):
    return any(x.isalpha() for x in s) and any(x.isdigit() for x in s)

' '.join([remove_digits(x) if is_combined(x) else x for x in test.split()])
```